# Can I inject Java code into my Controller $scope?

Tags: angularjs

I'm refactoring my app into AngularJS.

On my current JSP page there is Java code sent directly to page (not via AJAX). I normally reference it via ${myColl} and it works great.

Now with AngularJS, I've tried to pass that directly into my controller via:

```
.controller( "MyCtrl", function( $scope, MyService ) 
{
    $scope.myColl = ${myColl};
})
```

...but it doesn't work. Without rewriting my backend to get the data via AJAX how can I get that data into my controller?

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You just can't. You need an api call as this runs client-side unlike your jsp

Comment: @Apero -- No you don't - you can write in server info to the client on page load, as OP is asking.

Comment: For that the html page must also be a server-side template generated by a jsp running on the same server then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically use the `ng-init` function for writing server data to the client on load. Example:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="init('${myColl}')">

</div>
```

And the controller

```
.controller( "MyCtrl", function( $scope, MyService ) {
    $scope.init = function(col) {
        $scope.myColl = col;
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks great, thank you. One quick question: I'm only getting the fully qualified path of the object for col, i.e. com.company.path.ClassName instead of the object itself. I'm trying to do this now: ng-init="init('<c:out value="${myColl}"/>')" but still getting the same thing.

Comment: Not sure what do to about that..Java aint my wheelhouse :\